# Closed geodesics that cross one another frequently

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesics

Let $S$ be a smooth, closed, genus zero surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
$S$ has at least three simple (non-self-intersecting), closed geodesics by 
a theorem of Lyusternik and Shnirel'man.
Alternatively, any Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{S}^2$ leads to
at least three simple, closed geodesics.

---

[image: Ellipsoid]

         

<sup>(Image from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid).)</sup>

---

> ***Q1***. Is it true that, for every even $n > 2$, there is an $S$ that has a pair of
>   simple, closed geodesics that cross each other $n$ times?

On an ellipsoid, each pair of the simple, closed geodesics cross twice.
This feels like the generic situation.
But my guess is that the answer to Q1 is *Yes*; but an explicit construction
is eluding me.

> ***Q2***. Is there any sense in which $n=2$ crossings is the usual situation?

Comment: How about a case when a pair you are looking for is infinitely close close pair of geodesics (Jacobi equation)? It could be a starting point in order to construct an example…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to Q1 is 'yes'.  You can construct an explicit example as follows:  Take a band $B$ around a geodesic $e$ (for 'equator') on the round sphere of radius 1, say, between two parallel circles above and below it.  Now take the $n/2$-fold cover of this band, say, $\hat B$, and isometrically embed $\hat B$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a surface of revolution and then smoothly close it up by attaching two disks, which can be done while keeping the result a genus $0$ surface $\Sigma$ of revolution.  Now, the $n/2$-fold cover $\hat e$ of the geodesic $e$ will intersect all of the 'near-by' geodesics (which are also closed) exactly $n$ times.  (Here, 'near-by' means geodesics that stay within $\hat B\subset\Sigma$.)

Q2 does not seem to me to be well-formulated.

Comment: Great, Robert! Yes, Q2 is not well-formulated. I need to investigate papers such as Jean-François Le Gall's "Random geometry on the sphere" ([arXiv abs link](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.7943)).

Comment: It seems that another example could be constructed by simply adding $n$ spikes along an equator of the sphere; the two curves that zigzag between the pikes and locally minimize length would have the required intersection.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner: That's very simple and clever! Is it clear that those zig-zags are geodesics?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke:  I think it's clear 'physically' that there will exist such geodesics if you place $n$ large bumps long the equator so that it's easier to go around them than over them.  However, explicitly writing them down would be a challenge, I think.  Benoît's example has the advantage that it's 'stable' in some sense because those geodesics should persist under small perturbations of the metric.  On the other hand, my example produces a nonempty *open* set $U$ of closed geodesics on the sphere such that any two distinct geodesics in $U$ intersect in exactly $n$ points.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner & RobertBryant: Thanks to you both! Very insightful.